# timestamp в цифровую дату

Tags: javascript, node.js, дата, timestamp

Как сделать так, чтобы я отправлял timestamp и в ответ получил дату следующего вида: 02.01.2023?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать метод `toLocaleDateString()`

```js
const date = new Date()
const localeDate = date.toLocaleDateString()

console.log(date, localeDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот код, который работает как в клиентском, так и серверном JS:

```js
let d = Date.now()
console.log(d)
d = new Date(d)
d = d.toLocaleString('ru').split(',')[0]
console.log(d)
```

Думаю что такое решение закроет все варианты...

```js
let d = Date.now()
console.log(d)
d = new Date(d)
d = d.toISOString('ru').split('T')[0].replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/, '$3.$2.$1')
console.log(d)
```

Comment: У меня дата вида `mm/dd/yyyy`, нужно в аргументах toLocaleString повозиться :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 toLocaleString('ru')

Comment: @PavelNazarian спасибо за комментарий, но я уже в курсе :). Просто хотел уведомить автора ответа о проблеме.

Comment: @ΝNL993 ok, заодно и он прочитает )

Comment: @PavelNazarian ну пусть тогда и ссылка [на документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) будет.

Comment: @ΝNL993 все ещё нужно повозиться, [потому что...](https://imgur.com/cwHdHWY.png)

Comment: @eccs0103 совсем забыл что там такой формат :)

Comment: @eccs0103 погодите, а там разве так не должно быть? Посмотрите в вопрос, там именно такой формат и нужен.

Comment: @ΝNL993 не, это понятно. Я просто предлагаю более стабильный вариант: `d.toLocaleString(undefined, { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' });`

Comment: @eccs0103 только что заметил ваш комментарий, нет не походит, у меня также возвращается `mm/dd/yyyy`, а по вопросу должно быть `mm.dd.yyyy`